# PHP: How can I detect "@" in front of a call in my custom error handler?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a custom error handler attached to E_ALL PHP errors.

In an external lib the call `$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);` triggers PHP Warnings caught by my handler. Why? Shouldn't '@' make PHP ignore this?

My question: Is there any way I can detect (in my error handler) that '@' was used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look into the PHP manual revealed this:

> It is important to remember that the
>   standard PHP error handler is
>   completely bypassed. error_reporting()
>   settings will have no effect and your
>   error handler will be called
>   regardless - however you are still
>   able to read the current value of
>   error_reporting and act appropriately.
>   **Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement that
>   caused the error was prepended by the
>   @ error-control operator.**

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Using the @ operator is considered bad style by quite some people, btw.

Comment: There are some entirely valid cases for using @ though, like with unlink() when you don't care if the file exists or not. I'll agree it can be overused but there are definitely valid cases for it.

Answer (score 4):

Referencing the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler) on `set_error_handler` shows

> It is important to remember that the
> standard PHP error handler is
> completely bypassed. error_reporting()
> settings will have no effect and your
> error handler will be called
> regardless - however you are still
> able to read the current value of
> error_reporting and act appropriately.
> Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement that
> caused the error was prepended by the
> @ error-control operator.

So you could do this:

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) { // called with @
    return;
  }
  //....
}
```